# How to scroll back in the output of the last Ex command after pressing `g<`?

Tags: scrolling

From `:h g<`:

> The `g<` command can be used to see the last page of previous command output.
>   This is especially useful if you accidentally typed `<Space>` at the hit-enter
>   prompt.  You are then back at the hit-enter prompt **and can then scroll further
>   back**.
>   Note: If the output has been stopped with `q` at the more prompt, it will only
>   be displayed up to this point.
>   The previous command output is cleared when another command produces output.
>   The `g<` output is not redirected.

To test the `g<` command, I've started Vim with no configuration:

```
$ vim -Nu NONE
```

Then, I've tried to execute a command producing a long output:

```
:args $VIMRUNTIME/**/*.vim
:args
```

These commands populate the global arglist with all the `.vim` files in `$VIMRUNTIME`, and display its contents in Vim's internal pager.

- I've scrolled the output down to the bottom by keeping pressing `<space>`.
- I've pressed `Enter` to leave the pager, and get back to the buffer.
- I've pressed `g<` which re-displays the last page of the pager.

According to the last excerpt from the help you can scroll back after pressing `g<`.
And according to `:h hit-enter`, you can scroll back by pressing `k`, `Up`, `u`, `b`, or `g`, on the condition that `'compatible'` is reset and `'more'` is set:

> -> Press `'k'`, `<Up>`, `'u'`, `'b'` or `'g'` to scroll back in the messages.  This
>      works the same way as at the `|more-prompt|`.  Only works when `'compatible'`
>      is off and `'more'` is on.

But on my machine (Linux, Vim `8.0.1747`), pressing any of these keys doesn't scroll back, even though `'compatible'` is reset and `'more'` is set.

How to scroll back in the output of the last Ex command after pressing `g<`?

Comment: Same behavior for me on multiple systems. I'd guess it's either a bug or the last line of the help that you refer to ("scroll further back") shouldn't have been added and the first sentence is meant to be taken literally:  "...can be used to see _the last page_ of...output". The latter would make sense in light of the particular scenario mentioned by the help (accidentally hitting `space` after reaching the last page).